# A-Frame cursor with transparent image has a wrong draw order

Tags: javascript, three.js, transparency, aframe

I have a transparent image cursor, that is, an image that is a child of the camera.

```
<a-camera>
    <a-image position="0 0 -1" width="0.2" height="0.2" transparent="true" src="image.png">
</a-camera>
```

I’m having a tough time getting it to appear above other transparent images (such as the dinosaur). I'm seeing odd artifacts:

[image]

If used with `material="depthTest: false;"` it appears behind other transparent images:

[image]

There's a lot of material on StackOverflow about transparency with Three.js, but non of it pertains to A-Frame. I did try playing with the `renderOrder` property on various objects with no luck.

How can I solve this?

Relevant codepen:

https://codepen.io/OpherV/pen/oBqgBa?editors=1000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as it turns out, `sortObjects` is [explicitly changed](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/a6100f88e457d16eb812bcd970651438063042ce/src/core/scene/a-scene.js#L347) to false by A-Frame, even though in ThreeJS it's true by default. I'm not sure why, as this isn't documented anywhere.

It took a while to find this out but knowing this the solution is quite simple:

```
document.querySelector('a-scene').renderer.sortObjects = true;
```